# How to specify Ribbon Configuration for a specific Feign client in a Spring Boot project having multiple Feign clients?

Tags: spring-boot, ribbon, spring-cloud-feign, feign, netflix-ribbon

I have a spring boot project which is having two Feign Client's.
First Feign client (i.e. ***ServiceAProxy.class*** below), which will work on Service Discovery using Eureka or Consul.

```
@FeignClient(name="service-A")
public interface ServiceAProxy{
   @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
   String getResponse();
}
```

Second Feign client( *i.e **ServiceBProxy.class*** ), needs to have a set of **server list** which will be picked from Spring Cloud Configuration server or Apache zookeeper config server and will be passed to the ribbon client of **ServiceBProxy.class**. For that, I'm trying to add a Ribbon Client Configuration that will modify the ribbon server list. Below is the code for the second feign client.

```
@FeignClient(name="service-B")
@RibbonClient(name="service-B",configuration= ServiceBProxy.LocalRibbonClientConfig.class)
public interface ServiceBProxy{
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   String invalidateUsers();



@Configuration
class LocalRibbonClientConfig{
    
     @Value("${server-host1}") // fetched from config
     private String host1;

     @Value("${server-host2}") // fetched from config
     private String host2;


    @Bean
    public ServerList<Server> ribbonServerList() {
      return new StaticServerList<>(
              new Server(host1,8080),
              new Server(host2,8081)
      );
    }
}


}
```

Now, when I run the code, **ServiceBProxy.class** works as expected and picks the list of servers that was specified in the **LocalRibbonClientConfig.class**. 
But the problem is with the **ServiceAProxy.class** which was suppose to work on the basis of service discovery also starts to use the **LocalRibbonClientConfig**.

How can I only allow ServiceBProxy.class to use the custom ribbon configurations and other feign clients in the project to work as per their default behaviour.

Please guide on this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

wonder if you have tried contextId

```
@FeignClient(contextId = "fooClient", name = "stores", configuration = FooConfiguration.class)
```

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html